# MySql find out if record's id is in another table (in one query)

Tags: mysql, select

lets say I have 2 tables:

```
Table 1: (customers)
------------------------------------------
id | name | etc... | etc..


Table 2: (blockList)
------------------------
id
```

I want to know if each customer exists or not in blockList table as I'm looping thru customers table (in a single query, as a seperate field)

like this: `SELECT * FROM customers, blockList ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` probably.

Comment: `FROM customers, blockList` is cartesian product -- you need join

Comment: how many columns you have in blockList table? what does `id` means in blockList ? is it same as in customer?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes I have only one column named "id" and same as customer.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use join, example :

```
SELECT c.*, b.id AS id_blocklist
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN blocklist AS b ON b.id = c.id
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

If you want only records in blocklist, use `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

you must specify tables connection

```
SELECT * FROM customers as c, blockList as b WHERE c.id = b.id ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: it only lists customers in block list, not other ones.